# Is Ctrl + Break safe for terminating a Python program which has a thread?

Tags: python, multithreading, udp

I have written a simple program that has a thread running in the background while a UDP socket is waiting for events to be thrown by a device. The purpose of the thread is to execute a GET command every 3 minutes, which is a requirement specified in the specs documentation in order to be able to get the events.

In order to terminate the program whenever the user pleases to, what is the safe method to do? All I've been doing until now is to press Ctrl + Break (Ctrl + C doesn't work) but I'm trying to find other more ideal implementations, if there are any.

Does Ctrl + Break safely terminate the running thread as well?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by "safe"?  What bad effects are you concerned about?

Comment: @JeremyFriesner It seems to me that my implementation kills the thread by force and if not, may cause it to still run in the background? I'm not familiar with how they work so I would like to make sure just incase.

Comment: When a process is killed, all threads in that process are killed with it.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner I see! Thank you for clarifying this to me.